# Create a memory node

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How can I create a node with this form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{BRAM/.style=
        {
            draw=black,inner sep=0,fill=green!5,matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            nodes={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.15cm,draw,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
        }   
    }

    \matrix (dbtable) at (0,0) [BRAM]
    {
        \\
        \\
        |[minimum height=1cm]|{R0}
        \\
        \\
        \\
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: I want create a memory block node]

Comment: A `matrix` node is already a `node`, so what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: I need to use many of memory block, and I want to write only:

    \node[BRAM] (BRAMX) at (0,0) {R0};
    \node[BRAM] (BRAMY) at (0,4) {R1};
    \node[BRAM] (BRAMM) at (0,8) {M};

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

There exist several solutions for your question like using `\newcommand` or `pics`, next one uses a style.

The only drawback for this solution is that, when needed, `name` and `at` must be given as `node` options instead of using their more common syntax. I'm not sure why this happens but I think that this is related with using `node contents` instead of `{}`.

In any case it shortens typing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{BRAM/.style=
        {
               matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth, inner sep=0pt,
            nodes={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.15cm,draw,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
            row 3/.style={nodes={minimum height=1cm}},
            node contents={\\\\ #1\\\\\\}
        }   
    }

    \node[BRAM=R0, name=dbtable, at={(0,0)}];
    \node[BRAM=R1, name=db, at={(2,2)}];
    \node[BRAM=R2, name=db2, below right= 1 and 2 of db, nodes={fill=green!30}];

    %Double arrow between centers stopping at borders
    \draw[<->] (dbtable)--(db2);

    %Arrow between to particular anchor points
    \draw[->,red, thick] (dbtable.center)--(db.south east);

    %Line between to nodes with perpendicular coordinate system
    \draw[->,blue, line width=2pt] (dbtable)|-(db);
    \draw[->,orange] (db-2-1)-|(db2);

    %Curved lines 
    \draw[-,dashed,brown, very thick] (dbtable.south west) to[bend right] (db2.south);
    \draw[<-,green, line width=1mm] (dbtable.north west) to[out=150, in=120] (db-1-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: `BRAM` style with ports. It's not a perfect solution because using `fill` covers internal ports.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{BRAM/.style=
        {
               matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth, inner sep=0pt,
            nodes={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.15cm,draw,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
            row 3/.style={nodes={minimum height=1cm}},
            node contents={\\\\ #1\\\\\\},
            append after command={\pgfextra%
                \node[anchor=north west, font=\scriptsize, text=black] at (\tikzlastnode-3-1.north west) (\tikzlastnode-read) {Read\strut};
                \node[anchor=south west, font=\scriptsize] at (\tikzlastnode-3-1.south west) (\tikzlastnode-write) {Write\strut};
                \node[anchor=north east, font=\scriptsize] at (\tikzlastnode-3-1.north east) (\tikzlastnode-a) {a\strut};
                \node[anchor=south east, font=\scriptsize] at (\tikzlastnode-3-1.south east) (\tikzlastnode-b) {b\strut};
                \endpgfextra}
        }   
    }

    \node[BRAM=R0, name=dbtable, at={(0,0)}];
    \node[BRAM=R1, name=db, above right=2 and 1 of dbtable];

    %Line between to nodes with perpendicular coordinate system
    \draw[->,blue, line width=2pt] (dbtable-a.east)--++(0.5,0)|-(db-write);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**3rd version:**

Finally I've managed to draw the memory module with just one node (no more `matrix`). Horizontal lines are added with `path picture` and ports with `label`.
Horizontal lines are drawn proportionally to node's height but I don't know how to do the same with `labels`, so their position is fixed from nodes center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    BRAM/.style=
    {
        draw,
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=3cm,
            path picture={
                \foreach \i in {.1,.2,.8,.9}
              \draw ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!\i!(path picture bounding box.south west)$)--($(path picture bounding box.north east)!\i!(path picture bounding box.south east)$);
                },
        name=#1,
        label={[minimum height=1cm,font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,anchor=south west,name=\tikzlastnode-read]left:Read\strut},
        label={[minimum height=1cm,font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,anchor=north west,name=\tikzlastnode-write]left:Write\strut},
        label={[minimum height=1cm,font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,anchor=south east,name=\tikzlastnode-a]right:a\strut},
        label={[minimum height=1cm,font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,anchor=north east,name=\tikzlastnode-b]right:b\strut},
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[BRAM, name=R, fill=red] at (0,0) {R0};
    \node[BRAM, name=R1, minimum height=5cm] at (5,0) {R1};
    \draw (R-a)--(R1-read);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly that I wanted.
Sorry, can you recomend me a tutorial for create arrows between nodes.

Comment: @Sr.X    I've added some examples with arrows and lines between nodes. In any case, I'd suggest reading tutorials "A Picture for Karl's students" and "A Petri-net for Hagen" in [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Can you help me to put labels in the memory, represented ports, I need Port a and Port b in the right. data and write in the left. Than you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem, when I use
\node[BRAM=R0, name=dbtable, at={(0,0)}, nodes={fill=green!30}];
the Read, Write, a and b, disapear. How can I fill the node without overwrite the labels. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sr.X As I've already written this solution won't work with `fill`. I'll try to solve it tomorrow.

Comment: @Sr.X I've updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tnaks you very much, very nice design... you are very good.